# How to write data from pandas dataframe to a flat file with one value per row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, file-io, flat-file

I have data in CSV file as below

```
Date    Temperature_city_1  Temperature_city_2  Temperature_city_3  Which_destination
20140910    80  32  40  1
20140911    100 50  36  2
20140912    102 55  46  1
20140912    60  20  35  3
20140914    60  20  32  3
20140914    60  57  42  2
```

I need this data in a flat file in below format

```
Date
Temperature_city_1
Temperature_city_2
Temperature_city_3
Which_destination

20140910
80
32
40
1

20140911
100
50
36
2
...
```

I am trying to use pandas and write this data to a flat file but no luck.
Tried sample code but no luck

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do it using standard [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) method. You just have to specify `sep` parameter to be `\n` and the `line_terminator` to be `\n\n`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: 20140910,
  1: 20140911,
  2: 20140912,
  3: 20140912,
  4: 20140914,
  5: 20140914},
 'Temperature_city_1': {0: 80, 1: 100, 2: 102, 3: 60, 4: 60, 5: 60},
 'Temperature_city_2': {0: 32, 1: 50, 2: 55, 3: 20, 4: 20, 5: 57},
 'Temperature_city_3': {0: 40, 1: 36, 2: 46, 3: 35, 4: 32, 5: 42},
 'Which_destination': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 3, 4: 3, 5: 2}})

df.to_csv('my_csv_file.csv', sep='\n', line_terminator='\n\n', index=False)
```

And the resulting file will look like this:

```
Date
Temperature_city_1
Temperature_city_2
Temperature_city_3
Which_destination

20140910
80
32
40
1

20140911
100
50
36
2

20140912
102
55
46
1
...
```

I set `index` to be `False` so that each group of values wouldn't start with indices 0, 1, 2 ...